# How can I use the Design Tab in Visual Studio when designing XAML UI for a UWP App that uses Data Template in List View?

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, uwp, datatemplate, ui-design

This is a bit of a tricky question to put succinctly but here goes. Snippets have been included to get the point across.

This problem came about whilst trying to solve another problem, to which a solution was found on SO, but which required to right-click and edit the default style of a TextBox, which I can't do because the TextBox in question is part of a DataTemplate on a databound ListView which of course has no content at design time.

Here are some snippets: I use a data template to control the content/layout of my listview like so:

```
<ListView x:Name="DataItemList"
     ItemsSource="{x:Bind MasterMenuItem.DataObjects, Mode=OneWay}"
     SelectedItem="{x:Bind SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
     SelectionMode="Single"
     ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DataListItemTemplate}">
</ListView>
```

and a data template as a page/control resource

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DataListItemTemplate" x:DataType="vm:DataObjectListItem">
   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
      <Grid Height="40" Margin="10 0 0 0">
         <Grid.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="brush" Color="Silver"/>
         </Grid.Resources>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
         <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="240" />
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <Border Grid.Column="0" BorderBrush="{StaticResource brush}" BorderThickness="1 1 1 1">
         <FontIcon Name="Icon"
            Grid.Column="0"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            FontSize="32"
            Glyph="{x:Bind ListItemIcon}" />
      </Border>
      <Border Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="{StaticResource brush}" BorderThickness="1 1 1 1">
         <TextBlock Name="Data Object Name"
            Padding="6 4 6 4"
            Text="{x:Bind Name, Mode=OneWay}"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            FontWeight="Bold"
            TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"/>
      </Border>
   </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

When I view my page in the Design tab of visual studio (instead of the XAML tab) I see nothing useful, unlike if, for example, I put a TextBlock in my XAML with Text="Hello" I would be able to see 'Hello' in the Design tab and crucially Right-Click on it to do certain things...

Is there a way to 'populate' the list with some dummy data, or the text box with some dummy text in order to visualize the runtime layout in the Design tab?

Comment: You could try to pack the content of `DataTemplate` with `usercontrol`and set the   fake data to the usecontrol.

Comment: This [article about Design Time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/displaying-data-in-the-designer) might be helpful. Based on my previous trials I wouldn't say d:DataContext always works on UWP though.

Comment: Thanks @Burak, this is an excellent link, and I can see how it will apply to my problem. I'll try to feedback when I get on to actually trying it :)